# Simple averaging error, cannot find the right code

Tags: java, string, methods, average

I have finally written my program (took a while as I am a beginner) and what the program does is:

- Prints menu with 2 options, Average grades or Quit.
- If user chooses to average grades, it asks for their name. Then it tells them which order the grades are going to be averaged in.
- Then they enter any amount of grades, and press -1 and it will give you the sum of those grades along with the average. It does this 3 times, for the homework, quiz, and tests.

The last thing I need to do is average all 3 of those grades, and then output:

- `System.out.println( name, "'s average is ", + averageFinal );`

I was given this line from my assignment:

```
Final Average = 0.25*HomeworkAvg + 0.25*QuizAvg + 0.50*TestAvg = 77.87
```

Which I attempted to put in the program as:

```
averageFinal = 0.25*averageOne + 0.25*averageTwo + 0.50*averageThree;
```

But for some reason I am getting this strange compile error, which I can't seem to fix:

```
Assignment3.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
System.println( name, "'s final average is ", averageFinal );
       ^
symbol:   method println(String,String,double)
location: class System
1 error
```

Is there just a simple problem with my code, or do I have to change something in my string method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        int total;
        double averageOne;
        double averageTwo;
        double averageThree;
        double averageFinal;
        int grade;

        int gradeCounterone;
        int gradeCountertwo;
        int gradeCounterthree;

        gradeCounterone = 0;
        gradeCountertwo = 0;
        gradeCounterthree = 0;
        total = 0;

        String name;

        System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the students name:");
            name = input.next();

            System.out.println("Grades will be entered in this order: \n 1) Homework Grades \n 2) Quiz Grades \n 3) Test Grades ");

            {
                System.out.println("Enter homework grades, press -1 when finished:");
                grade = input.nextInt();

                while (grade != -1) {
                    total = total + grade;
                    gradeCounterone = gradeCounterone + 1;

                    System.out.println("Enter homework grades, press -1 when finished:");
                    grade = input.nextInt();

                }
                if (gradeCounterone != 0) {
                    averageOne = (double) total / gradeCounterone;

                    System.out.printf("\nThe total of the %d homework grades is %d\n", gradeCounterone, total);
                    System.out.printf("\nThe average of the homework grades is %.2f\n ", averageOne);

                }

                // second loop for quiz grades

                System.out.println("\nEnter quiz grades, press -1 when finished:");
                grade = input.nextInt();

                while (grade != -1) {
                    total = total + grade;
                    gradeCountertwo = gradeCountertwo + 1;

                    System.out.println("Enter quiz grades, press -1 when finished:");
                    grade = input.nextInt();

                }
                if (gradeCountertwo != 0) {

                    averageTwo = (double) total / gradeCountertwo;

                    System.out.printf("\nThe total of the %d quiz grades is %d\n", gradeCountertwo, total);
                    System.out.printf("\nThe average of the quiz grades is %.2f\n ", averageTwo);

                }

                // third loop for test grades

                System.out.println("\nEnter test grades, press -1 when finished:");
                grade = input.nextInt();

                while (grade != -1) {
                    total = total + grade;
                    gradeCounterthree = gradeCounterthree + 1;

                    System.out.println("Enter test grades, press -1 when finished:");
                    grade = input.nextInt();

                }
                if (gradeCounterthree != 0) {

                    averageThree = (double) total / gradeCounterthree;

                    System.out.printf("\nThe total of the %d test grades is %d\n", gradeCounterthree, total);
                    System.out.printf("\nThe average of the test grades is %.2f\n ", averageThree);

                }

                averageFinal = 0.25 * averageOne + 0.25 * averageTwo + 0.50 * averageThree;
                System.println(name, "'s final average is ", averageFinal);

            }

        } else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Exiting program.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, exiting program.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
System.out.println( name + " s final average is " + averageFinal );
```

instead of

```
System.println( name, "' s final average is ", averageFinal );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
System.println( name, "'s final average is ", averageFinal );
```

try

```
System.out.println( name + "'s final average is " + averageFinal );
```

You can also get this info from the JDK docs.

Comment: Also I feel like my final averaging line is incorrect, is there any place to find the correct code? Or is that what you meant about finding it in the JDK docs

Answer (score 0):

its a typo.

Its not

```
System.println();
```

It's

```
System.out.println();
```

Refer to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)

Answer (score 0):

There's a *few* issues here.

Notwithstanding the obvious:  It's `System.out.println`.  And, you concatenate `String`s together with `+`:

```
System.out.println(name + "'s final average is " + averageFinal);
```

Now, after you fix that code, then you get the issue of these variables not being initialized:

```
averageFinal = 0.25 * averageOne + 0.25 * averageTwo + 0.50 * averageThree;
```

Neither `averageOne`, `averageTwo` nor `averageThree` are guaranteed, through the natural flow of the program, to be initialized - seems like they're being initialized behind some `if` statements.

It'd be straightforward to initialize them to zero, just in case you didn't hit any of your `if` statements:

```
double averageOne = 0;
double averageTwo = 0;
double averageThree = 0;
```